# Get keyword of the search with struts Liferay

Tags: search, liferay, hook, struts-1, liferay-hook

I want get the keywords of the search with the portlet of Search. I saw that in the url appear:  "struts_action=/search/seach" then I looked for in strut-config.xml and find:
    action path="/search/search" forward="portlet.search.search"

I am trying to do a strut but I don't know very much about struts and it doesn't work. This is the code of 'liferay-hook.xml':

```
<portal-properties>portal.properties</portal-properties>
<struts-action>
    <struts-action-path>/search/search</struts-action-path>
    <struts-action-impl>com.segmentationProject.searchAction.struts.SearchAction</struts-action-impl>
</struts-action>
```

portal.properties:
    auth.public.paths=/search/search

SearchAction.java:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.struts.BaseStrutsAction;

public class SearchAction extends BaseStrutsPortletAction {  
    @Override
    public void processAction(StrutsPortletAction originalStrutsPortletAction, PortletConfig portletConfig, ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("inside the process ");
        super.processAction(originalStrutsPortletAction, portletConfig, actionRequest, actionResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public String render(StrutsPortletAction originalStrutsPortletAction,PortletConfig portletConfig, RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("inside the render");
        return super.render(portletConfig, renderRequest, renderResponse);
    }
}
```

Any idea about I missing or do wrong? I only want get the keywords and then do the search normally. 
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need the search keyword? Maybe it is better to hook search JSP.

Comment: I need the search keyword because I want save if the user has searched some things. I thought in the strut action because I saw it in the url. I am a bit newbie in Liferay, which is the difference between do a hook of JSP and strut action? I don't want change the funcionality of the search.

Comment: Thanks Aleksandr M. I did the hook of search.jsp and with this code: " String kw = ParamUtil.getString(request, "keywords");" I obtain the keywords.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this one will do the job :

```
String keywords = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "keywords");
```

`ParamUtil` use the portlet namespace to retrieve parameters.

Comment: You can use this in the `SearchAction` described by Sandra in the question :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use originalStrutsPortletAction instead of super.

```
super.processAction(originalStrutsPortletAction, portletConfig, actionRequest, actionResponse);
}
```

just replace super by originalStrutsPortletAction

```
    originalStrutsPortletAction .processAction(originalStrutsPortletAction, portletConfig, actionRequest, actionResponse);
}
```